# How can I pass a generic type used in a function?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a function type in `typescript` as below:

```
export type NextFunType = <E, T>(event: E, context: Context) => Promise<T>;
```

Then I create a function with `NextFunType` as below:

```
const next: NextFunType = (event: string, context: Context) => {
  return Promise.resolve(true);
};
```

But I got an error:

```
Type '(event: string, context: Context) => Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'NextFunType'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'E' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

How can I create a function with a generic type?

Comment: Do you control type `NextFunType` or it is coming from third party? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BAHsKBeKBvKAzOOALigGdgAnASwQHMoBfAbgCgXRIoA5VYAMQCuCACrgIAHgCiAGijCAfJigAKCADcISEjKgBjRMjQl4SXgEpMigAoU4AWyqkJC1i30JyUBLxI80gkTFxcmo6WQAjQgAbCABDBEUsVQ0tMkoaWll3Q2BjA3NLHBYoKAoIYAEKBCgbe0cIADoy0jgojWVKAQgzVmYgA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to declare your type is:

```
export type NextFunType<E, T> = (event: E, context: any) => Promise<T>;
```

and when you initialize the variable, you'll need to pass the types for `E` and `T`

```
 const next: NextFunType<string, boolean> = (event: string, context: any) => {
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    };
```